# jaxws-tools-maven-plugin wsconsume encoding

Tags: maven, jboss, wsdl

I am trying to generate the Java code to consume a WSDL using `jaxws-tools-maven-plugin`, but I cannot find a way to specify the encoding of the generated code and it keeps giving me compilation warnings (the maven project is set to UTF-8).

The [JBoss wsconsume documentation page](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/wsconsume) defines an `<encoding/>` configuration option, but when I write the `pom.xml` that option is not available in the content assist (while the others listed in the page do appear) and the compilation of the code generates a lot of warnings of `unmappable character for encoding UTF-8`.

Here is an excerpt of my effective pom:

```
<properties>
   <version.org.jboss.as.plugins.maven.plugin>7.3.Final</version.org.jboss.as.plugins.maven.plugin>
   <version.org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.6.0>3.0.0.Final</version.org.jboss.spec.jboss.javaee.6.0>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<plugin>
   <groupId>org.jboss.ws.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jaxws-tools-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>wsconsume</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <wsdls>
            <wsdl>myDirectory/src/main/wsdl/custody.wsdl</wsdl>
          </wsdls>
          <sourceDirectory>myDirectory/src/main/generated</sourceDirectory>
          <targetPackage>org.acme.mypackage</targetPackage>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any solution?

Comment: Are your WSDL's correctly UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes it is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"...`

Comment: I haven't asked if the encoding is given in the XML I have asked if the file is correctly encoded...Check the generated class where exactly the wrong encodings happen...

Comment: Using IntelliJ I am getting the warning that using encoding is not allowed at this position.